# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test_schema.#sql-44c_2a' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, constraints

So, I've recreated the issue I'm having with more readable code. I run this sql file in my mysql prompt:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test_schema 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;

USE test_schema ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table test_schema.table_one
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_one (
    table_one_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    table_one_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (table_one_id, table_one_name)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table test_schema.table_two
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_two (
    table_two_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    table_two_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    table_one_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (table_two_id)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE table_two ADD FOREIGN KEY (table_one_name) REFERENCES table_one(table_one_name);
```

The output I get from the prompt is:

```
mysql> source test-database.sql;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test_schema.#sql-44c_2a' (errno: 150)
```

If I run 'SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;' I get the following details

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
150603  9:22:25 Error in foreign key constraint of table test_schema/#sql-44c_2a:
FOREIGN KEY (table_one_name) REFERENCES table_one(table_one_name):
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.
```

I've searched for this issue and almost every one say that it's about:
1) Not having the same type
 - They're both "VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL" (tried letting the one in table_two be null, didn't alter the error-message)
2) The foreign key not being a primary key
 - table_one_name is a primary key in table_one together with table_one_id
3) Make sure that the Charset and Collate options are the same both at the table level
 - What does this mean? I suppose they are since I don't change them?

Please help
// Finbel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a Foreign Key the two fields must be INDEXed.

Try this:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table test_schema.table_one
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_one (
    table_one_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    table_one_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (table_one_id, table_one_name),
    KEY `one_name` (`table_one_name`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table test_schema.table_two
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_two (
    table_two_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    table_two_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    table_one_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (table_two_id),
    KEY `two_name` (`table_two_name`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE table_two  ADD FOREIGN KEY (table_one_name) REFERENCES table_one(table_one_name);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any tip on where I can read up on indexing? For some reason they skipped that whole part in my database-course.

Comment: MySql documentation would be the place to start and from there other posts about the issue, it is very important to use INDEX in your tables, there are different types of INDEX but for me the rule is that for every field that you search by MUST have an INDEX